# How to implement Where-Object in SQL-Invoke command

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to filter some tables from my database which exists in my solution folder. I want to filter all tables that I am pulling from SQL Server:

```
$existingTables = "Table1", "Table2", "Table3", "Table4"

#getting all tables except existing ones
#SqlQuery = "SELECT name FROM sys.Tables order by name asc"
$filteredTables = ((Invoke-SQL -DataSource $ServerName -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -UserID $UserID -Password $Password -SqlCommand $SQLQuery).name | ? {$_ -notcontains $existingTables})
#$filteredTables returns all tables, including the existing ones...
```

I've tried `$_.name` and it is the same result.

Comment: Why not add a `where name not in()` into the select statement?

Comment: `$_ -notcontains $addedTables` -> `$addedTables -notcontains $_`. You switched the operands. For `-[not]contains` the correct order is `<reference_array> -notcontains <item>`. Otherwise use `-[not]in` (`<item> -notin <reference_array>`). The latter is not available prior to PowerShell v3, though.

Comment: Should `$addedTables` be `$existingTables`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the operands of the [`-notcontains` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-3.0#-notcontains) in the wrong order. The correct syntax is

```
reference_array -notcontains item
```

In your case:

```
$existingTables -notcontains $_
```

or

```
$existingTables -notcontains $_.Name
```

if you don't expand the property `Name`.

If you want to use the reference array as the second operand you must use the [`-notin` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-3.0#-notin):

```
$_ -notin $existingTables
```

However, that operator is not available prior to PowerShell v3.

Alternatively, you could add an exclude clause to your SQL statement, as [@vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631510/how-to-implement-where-object-in-sql-invoke-command#comment94123046_53631510) suggested in the comments. Take care to not open yourself to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) when doing that, though.

*Don't* do this:

```
$SQLQuery = @"
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE name NOT IN ('$($existingTables[0])', '$($existingTables[1])', ...)
"@
```

Use a [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) (or "parameterized query" as Microsoft calls them). I don't recognize the cmdlet you're using, though (doesn't seem to be `Invoke-Sqlcmd`), so I can't tell you how to do it with that cmdlet.

Comment: It crossed on my mind that I replaced the order but I didn't try :) Thank you very much!